# create sequence vector for each level of other column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data table` something like this. This is just a sample. `col1` has a lot more `levels`

```
col1      col2
A          231
A          532
A          764
A          532
B          432
B          432
B          443
B          343 
B          643
B          322
B          334
```

What I want is the following

```
col1      col2      squence_per_col1
A          231           1 
A          532           2
A          764           3
A          532           4 
B          432           1
B          432           2 
B          443           3
B          343           4
B          643           5
B          322           6 
B          334           7
```

Basically I want to create sequence column for each `level` of `col1` in a very efficient manner. Please not that this is a **data.table.** Please provide a solution with data table syntax.

How do I do it?

Comment: Just use `sequence` and `.N` or `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Comment: `dt[,1:.N,col1]` and `getanID(dt, 'col1')[]`

Comment: or `dt[, rleid(col2), col1]` (which gives a slightly different effect)